# How exactly use quickblox in android?

Tags: android, quickblox

I take reference from official website https://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Download_Android_SDK

gradle compile succeed:

```
    repositories {
            maven {
                url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
            }
        }
            dependencies {
                 compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:2.5.1@aar"   
                 compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.5.1@aar") {
                 transitive=true
            }
        }
```

then i use the code first:
I had the APP_ID...etc

```
    QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);

    QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);
```

Second step :
I reference Guide: Getting Started with Chat API https://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Guide:_Getting_Started_with_Chat_API

```
//Prepare chat service
QBChatService.setDebugEnabled(true); // enable chat logging

        QBChatService.setDefaultPacketReplyTimeout(10000);//set reply timeout in milliseconds for connection's packet.
        //Can be used for events like login, join to dialog to increase waiting response time from server if network is slow.


        //configure chat socket
        QBChatService.ConfigurationBuilder chatServiceConfigurationBuilder = new QBChatService.ConfigurationBuilder();
        chatServiceConfigurationBuilder.setSocketTimeout(60); //Sets chat socket's read timeout in seconds
        chatServiceConfigurationBuilder.setKeepAlive(true); //Sets connection socket's keepAlive option.
        chatServiceConfigurationBuilder.setUseTls(true); //Sets the TLS security mode used when making the connection. By default TLS is disabled.
```

QBChatService.setConfigurationBuilder(chatServiceConfigurationBuilder);

It has a issue that i can't import `QBChatService.ConfigurationBuilder`
so i try to change gradle to `compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.6.1")`

now QBChatService.ConfigurationBuilder can be import

Third step:
I take the official step use the code:

```
// Initialise Chat service
        final QBChatService chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();

        final QBUser user = new QBUser("garrysantos", "garrysantospass");

        QBAuth.createSession(user, new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession qbSession, Bundle bundle) {

                // success, login to chat

                user.setId(qbSession.getUserId());

                chatService.login(user, new QBEntityCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Object o, Bundle bundle) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

            }
        });


        //To handle different connection states use ConnectionListener:
        ConnectionListener connectionListener = new ConnectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void connected(XMPPConnection xmppConnection) {

            }

            @Override
            public void authenticated(XMPPConnection xmppConnection, boolean b) {

            }

            @Override
            public void connectionClosed() {

            }

            @Override
            public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
                // connection closed on error. It will be established soon
            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectionSuccessful() {

            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectingIn(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {

            }
        };

        QBChatService.getInstance().addConnectionListener(connectionListener);


        //logOut
        boolean isLoggedIn = chatService.isLoggedIn();
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            return;
        }

        chatService.logout(new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {
                //success
                chatService.destroy();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

            }
        });

        //By default Android SDK reconnects automatically when connection to server is lost.
        //But there is a way to disable this and then manage this manually:
        QBChatService.getInstance().setReconnectionAllowed(false);
```

when i use the step about `QBChatDialog` , it can't be import again....

```
ArrayList<Integer> occupantIdsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        occupantIdsList.add(34);
        occupantIdsList.add(17);

        QBChatDialog dialog = new QBChatDialog();
        dialog.setName("Chat with Garry and John");
        dialog.setPhoto("1786");
        dialog.setType(QBDialogType.GROUP);
        dialog.setOccupantsIds(occupantIdsList);

//or just use DialogUtils
//for creating PRIVATE dialog
//QBChatDialog dialog = DialogUtils.buildPrivateDialog(recipientId);

//for creating GROUP dialog
        QBChatDialog dialog = DialogUtils.buildDialog("Chat with Garry and John", QBDialogType.GROUP, occupantIdsList);

        QBRestChatService.createChatDialog(dialog).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog result, Bundle params) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException responseException) {

            }
        });
```

so i try to change gradle compile `compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.0")`

now `QBChatDialog` can be imported.

but it has another issues...

```
Can't not resolve symbol 'QBSettings' and 'QBSession'
```

I'm angry now , are you kidding me ?

Why the official step cheat me step by step ?

I'm tired... what should i do ?

### Somebody can save me please , any help would be appreciated !

According @Jagapathi kindly responding , i update my code , the next issue is that i can't log in

My toast shows Login error when i click the login button:

```
private void setupQuickBlox() {
        QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
        QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);
        QBSettings.getInstance().setAutoCreateSession(true);

        //login to quickblox
        String enterAccount = editAccount.getText().toString();
        String enterPassword = editPassword.getText().toString();
        Log.d(TAG,enterAccount);
        Log.d(TAG,enterPassword);
        final QBUser user = new QBUser(enterAccount, enterPassword);
        //login
        QBUsers.signIn(user).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBUser qbUser, Bundle bundle) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor s = getSharedPreferences("QBid", 0).edit();
                s.putString("id", user.getId().toString());
                s.apply();
                Log.d(TAG,user.getId().toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login success with quickblox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

the code is under my onCreat , so it shows Login error when i satrt the app of course , but when i enter account and password , it still shows Login error , why?  I check the log , i can see the account and password that i typed , but i can't see `user.getId().toString()` on my log , what step is wrong ?
i check the account is correct:
[image]

[image]

Here is my key:

```
static final String APP_ID = "50427";
    static final String AUTH_KEY = "naMGFKMshdLC3s4";
    static final String AUTH_SECRET = "GP8ey4GsQXt2TGu";
    static final String ACCOUNT_KEY = "dHYgix3we3bxxsvMqyuR";
```

Here is my test Account key:
[image]

[image]

My button onClcik:

```
buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setupQuickBlox();
            }
        });
```

Here is my log:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can guide you with Quickblox I am in same position when I started using quickblox.

**step 1:-**

```
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.3.0@aar'
compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.0@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
```

This is for latest version of quickblox. So don't use old versions .

**step 2:-**

This is my SetUp Quickblox function you don't forgot to use app_id Auth_key auth_secret and account_key

```
 private void SetupQuickBlox() {

    QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
    QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);
    QBSettings.getInstance().setAutoCreateSession(true);

    //login to quickblog for


    final QBUser user=new QBUser("USER_NAME OF USER","PASSWORD OF USER");
    // Login
    QBUsers.signIn(user).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {
            // success
            SharedPreferences.Editor s=getSharedPreferences("QBid",0).edit();
            s.putString("id",user.getId().toString());
            s.apply();
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Login succes with quickblox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException error) {
            // error
        }
    });
}
```

**step:- 3**

You are all done Login with quickblox is successful so you can now request DIALOGS or CREATE DIALOg Sessions are automatically created in latest version.

**Create New Dialog**

```
private void NewMessage() {
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            QBChatDialog dialog = DialogUtils.buildPrivateDialog("USER_ID of other user");
            dialog.setName("tester1");

            QBRestChatService.createChatDialog(dialog).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog result, Bundle params) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException responseException) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Request List Of Dialog Of Logged In User**

I Used ListView And Dialogs result will be in array list which contains LIST of  QBCHATDIALOG

```
private void receiveChatList() {
    QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
    requestBuilder.setLimit(100);

    QBRestChatService.getChatDialogs(null, requestBuilder).performAsync(
            new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBChatDialog>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final ArrayList<QBChatDialog> result, Bundle params) {
                    int totalEntries = params.getInt("total_entries");
                    Log.wtf("chat",""+result);
                    TrumeMsgAdapter adapter=new TrumeMsgAdapter(TrueMeMessagesActivity.this,result);
                    chatlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    chatlistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(TrueMeMessagesActivity.this,ChatingActivity.class).putExtra("dialog",result.get(position)));
                        }
                    });

                }
                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException responseException) {

                }
            });
}
```

**My Adapter Code**

```
public class TrumeMsgAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<QBChatDialog> chatlist;
private Context context;

public TrumeMsgAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<QBChatDialog> chatlist){
    this.chatlist=chatlist;
    this.context=c;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return chatlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View List;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        List = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trume_msg_adapter, null);
        TextView username=(TextView) List.findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        TextView lastmessage=(TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.lastmessage);
        username.setText(chatlist.get(position).getName());
        lastmessage.setText(chatlist.get(position).getLastMessage());
    } else {
        List = convertView;
        TextView username=(TextView) List.findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        TextView lastmessage=(TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.lastmessage);
        username.setText(chatlist.get(position).getName());
        lastmessage.setText(chatlist.get(position).getLastMessage());
    }

    return List;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! There is no responding in recently days , i do not respect any more for help even though , i will try your step by step to figure our my issue , if i have any question that i  will ask for your help again . Thanks @Jagapathi !

Comment: Thanks for the upvote I added code upto getting chat dialogs For getting chat messages have any trouble i can help  have a good day

Comment: Hi @Jagapathi , should i forget my step just follow your guide ?

I can't log in , i update my issue .

Comment: all your keys are perfect?   My Login code works perfect as i am working on quickblox chat two days back

Comment: u r using manual login then separate initialization and login with two different function

Comment: I think the key is correct , i update it , take a look please , and my button function call SetUpQuickBlox(); again , can you see that may be what's the issue ?

Comment: can u post the error here in comment   just print E in Onerror function

Comment: E/error: com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException: User's email unconfirmed      this is the error

Comment: but there is no exception happen , do you mean that i should put the try-catch for QBResponseException ?

Comment: The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to validation errors. Possible causes:
create a user with existent login or email.
provide values in wrong format to create some object.


create a another user for testing

Comment: i got it , i update it , the comments is it,take a look please !

Comment: that means that should i key in user's email ?

Comment: Strange , i check the account , i had email for Rogan.

Comment: which user r u using for login ?                Try to create seperate user with diffrent email and try

Comment: Ping me ur social site contact to discuss way to many comments here .

Comment: It's Rogan , his data that include three variables with Email、Login、Password , i also create a new user that is SteveNash , it's no working too. i update it on question , the social site that the account is Logan

Comment: @Jagapathi 
your answer is very useful after stuck in this chat documentation for 3 days, but I still stuck in some issues, If you kindly help me I will be very grateful for that.
1- if I need to create a new dialog and I don't have the other user Id, just I have it's email how to get user id?
I tried to get it by API but I stuck in how to get QB-Token header.